# Not able to write a string to a *char[]

Tags: c, arrays, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been at this for hours with little progress made. I need to know why exactly my program is crashing when scanf() is called. The error message: "Segmentation fault; core dumped" leads me to believe that I'm not allocating memory to the dynamic array correctly. If this is the case could someone tell me how I can correctly allocate memory to add one struct to the array?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 *
 */


enum Subject{
    SER = 0, EGR = 1, CSE = 2, EEE = 3
};
 struct Course{
    enum Subject sub;
    int number;
    char instructor_name[1024];
    int credit_hours;
}*course_collection;


int total_courses = 0;
int total_credits = 0;
void course_insert();
void resizeArray();


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int choice = 0;
    while(choice != 4){
    printf("Welcome to ASU, please choose from the menu"
            "choices.\n\n");
    printf("_____________________________________________\n\n");

    printf("Menu:\n 1.Add a class\n 2. Remove a class\n"
            " 3.Show classes\n 4.Quit");
    printf("\n\nTotal credit hours: %d\n\n", total_credits);


    printf("\n\n_________________________________________");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 1){
        resize_array(total_courses);
        course_insert();
    }

    else if(choice == 3)
        print_courses();

    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}

void resize_array(int total_courses) {
    course_collection = malloc(total_courses +
            sizeof(course_collection));
}

void print_courses() {
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < total_courses; i++){
        printf("\nInstructor: %s\n\n",
                course_collection[i].instructor_name);
    }
}

void course_insert(){
    printf("\n\nEnter the instructor's name\n\n");
    scanf("%s" , course_collection[total_courses].instructor_name);
    total_courses++;
}
```

```
//will crash just after scanf();
//must press 1 & enter for correct output
```

After entering a few instructor names I choose the third option from the menu and that should iterate through the array and print each instructor's name but all I get are blanks lines and the last instructor name I imputed.

UPDATE
@user3545894 I've tried this and it seems to work fine but I still get the issue with the output not being correct. I should be able to iterate through  the array and print the strings in each subscript.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Or step through the code in your own debugger.

Comment: I don't see why this code should work. You never actually create an array.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: `course_collection` is a pointer, so you probably want `sizeof *course_collection`. I don't see `total_courses` defined anyplace, but did you mean: `course_collection = malloc(sizeof *course_collection * total_courses);`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem came from ***malloc(total_courses + sizeof(course_collection))***

You only allocate array of pointer of course_collection.
You need allocate memory for whole the *struct Course*

It should be **malloc(total_courses * sizeof(struct Course))**

Answer (score 0):

User this malloc(total_courses + sizeof(struct Course)) instead of malloc(total_courses + sizeof(course_collection))

segmentation fault due to memory allocation mostly for arrays
arr[n] we use it till '0' to 'n-1' { carefully observe not 'n'}